# Best tool to validate UI mockups by overlaying them

Tags: tools, mac-os-x, frontend-development, transparency

I'm looking for a solution/tool that will allow me to validate that my frontend project is pixel-perfectly aligned with the Photoshop mockups.

Best would be to make the browser window transparent - that way I could lay it over the mockups and see if they align as they should. Unfortunately, I cannot find such a tool for MacOS. Safari used to have "Use transparent window" debug feature, however it's missing in Catalina. There used to be tools like [afloat](https://github.com/rwu823/afloat) and [afloax](https://github.com/jslegendre/AfloatX) however they don't work with Catalina - and even if they did, they need to disable SIP, which is impossible in corporate environment for security reasons.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are having to do this, I suggest that a better design and handover process needs to be in place otherwise the effort and complexity won't scale for bigger projects.

Comment: @MichaelLai what do you mean? How could I tune the process to help with this issue? The CSS from mockup designs cannot be easily copy-pasted, they don't scale and respond to changes properly...

Comment: These types of tools fit into the category of UX tools known as handoff tools. You'll find a list of them at the UX Tools website (https://uxtools.co/tools/handoff), including Zeplin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeplin has this feature as it seems..

https://support.zeplin.io/en/articles/1437093-comparing-app-website-with-designs-using-pop-out

Answer (score 0):

If this was an iOS project, you can use the [Flawless app](https://flawlessapp.io/) but I really have not come across a tool for web front end that handles this scenario.

A hack I have personally used in the past is to use take a full-page screenshot of each web front end with [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en) then place this either on top of the UI design or just side by side using artboards.